# Similar Acronyms with glossaries

Tags: glossaries-extra

How to generate the following sentences with the glossaries functionality:

> In operational phase 1 (OP1) we did such. In the following OP2 and OP3
>   we changed the settings.

The tex code would look something like:

```
In \gls{OP1} we did such. In the following \gls{OP2} and \gls{OP3} we changed the settings.
```

Of course the acronym definitions

```
\newacronym{OP1}{OP1}{operation phase~1}
\newacronym{OP2}{OP2}{operation phase~2}
\newacronym{OP2}{OP2}{operation phase~2}
```

would result in the expansion of all acronyms, whereas I need only the first phrase to expand. Is this functionality included or problematic?

Compilable example document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         

\usepackage[acronym, nomain, nonumberlist, toc, automake=immediate]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\makeglossaries


\newacronym{OP1}{OP1}{operation phase~1}
\newacronym{OP2}{OP2}{operation phase~2}
\newacronym{OP3}{OP3}{operation phase~3}

\begin{document}
In \gls{OP1} we did such. In the following \gls{OP2} and \gls{OP3} we changed the settings.

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please make a short compilable MWE? Do you want all three abbreviations to show in the list of abbreviations?

Comment: Yes, all three should be in the list of abbreviations.

Comment: Added compilable MWE

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired output using a combination of `\glsentryshort` and `\glsadd` as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}         

\usepackage[acronym, nomain, nonumberlist, toc, automake]{glossaries-extra}
\setabbreviationstyle[acronym]{long-short-user}

\makeglossaries


\newacronym{OP1}{OP1}{operation phase~1}
\newacronym{OP2}{OP2}{operation phase~2}
\newacronym{OP3}{OP3}{operation phase~3}

\begin{document}
In \gls{OP1} we did such. In the following \glsentryshort{OP2} and \glsentryshort{OP3} we changed the settings.


\printglossaries
\glsadd{OP2}\glsadd{OP3}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, is there no better way? The way i see it, this solution defies the whole point of glossaries since you need to rearrange everything if you change the order.